# Text messaging App android getting threads to update

Tags: java, android, android-listview

```
private ArrayList<String> conversation = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private String phoneNumber;     
ListView listView;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.converse_view);

    this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            conversation);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.conversation);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}



protected void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
   setContentView(R.layout.converse_view);
   this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}


public void changeNumber(String phoneNumber2) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber2;

}

public void addText(String message) {
    conversation.add(message);

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public boolean equals(converseView other) {
    return this.phoneNumber.equals(other.phoneNumber);
}
```

I am creating a text messaging app this is my class for the conversation view screen. 
addText() is called when you click the send button. How do i get the list view to update so i can see what text messages where send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the message to the adapter, and notify the adapter that the list has changed.

```
if (this.adapter!=null)
{
  this.adapter.add(message);
  this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Basically, the last time that the adapter knows the state of conversation is at:

```
this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
        conversation);
```

This will add everything from the ArrayList to the ArrayAdapter, but it doesn't link them together in any way.

Comment: Sounds like the activity hadn't been started... I guess you could check to make sure the adapter is set first, as my edit does.

Comment: Why would i add message to adapter. Shouldn't i be adding it to my ArrayList<String> conversation as that is the input to the adapter.

Or am i doing that wrong

Comment: Well, basically the adapter doesn't keep a reference to the ArrayList. You have to add it to the adapter directly. When you created it, you passed a list of values to start out with, but if you add one, it has to be added to the adapter.

Comment: So the original values in the array list don't matter?

Also are my onResume() and on start methods written correctly

Comment: No, they do matter, they get passed in when you create the arrayAdapter. Anything that happens to the ArrayList after the ArrayAdapter doesn't matter.

Comment: Using the code you gave me doesn't update the adapter. 
I feel that is because my adapter and my ListView are only set in the onCreate() method, which from my understanding is only called when i create the object.

How would i get my ListView to update every time i go into the Activity

Comment: So, you are switching back and forth into and out of the activity? You would need to store the state of the ArrayList, and re-populate it.

Comment: Basically i have a list view of Phone Numbers on my main screen. 
When one of these is click it opens and instance of Conversation View.
Conversation view is the class i have written above, it is suppose to have all the messages you sent to that number.

Comment: How would I link the arrayList and the Adapter. 

Sorry i have basically one semester of coding experience so this is all somewhat confusing to me.

Comment: If you want to record all of the conversation, I suggest you start a database. That's far beyond the original question, but I will point you to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: What would be the advantage in using a SQL database over a arrayList.
Is there anyway i could just get my implementation to work

Comment: There are quite a few, but basically it will persist easier between sessions, and allow you to do filtering easier, among others.

Comment: Bascially i just wanna know what i did wrong with mine. How do i get the adapter to display when i go into the activity